# How to add a LabelItem to PlotItem

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I want to make the label item of a plot clickable, that is, I can click the bottom or left label of a plot to call a menu.

My attempt:

The most obvious way is to rewrite the LabelItem class and overwrite the mousePressEvent() function, however, I did not see any methods in docs to add a LabelItem to a PlotItem at correct position. Code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class ClickableLabelItem(pg.LabelItem):

    def __init__(self, text='No Data'):
        super(ClickableLabelItem, self).__init__()
        self.setText(text, justify='left')

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        print('clicked')


class AbstractPlot(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AbstractPlot, self).__init__()

        self.pl = pg.PlotItem()
        self.addItem(self.pl)

        left_label = ClickableLabelItem()
        self.pl.addItem(left_label)
        # "Clicked" is printed but the label
        # appears at wrong position


if __name__ == "__main__":


    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication([])
    win = QMainWindow()
    plot = AbstractPlot()
    win.setCentralWidget(plot)
    win.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(Qt.QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Label appears at wrong position

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear, is your problem that "clicked" is not printed or that the ClickableLabelItem is in the wrong position?

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, I will edit my problem, "clicked" is printed here, but the label is in the wrong position.

Comment: 1. You could provide a [MRE], add the imports and the other elements to be able to execute your code. 2. Also add an image of what you are obtaining and another of what you want to obtain. 3. Please read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc updated

Comment: what is the correct position?

Comment: As a Label Item, it should be at left to the y-axis, or below the x-axis

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect in the label associated with the axis then you can override the mousePressEvent method of GraphicsLayoutWidget and compare the item associated with the point pressed by the mouse.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import pyqtgraph as pg


class AbstractPlot(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AbstractPlot, self).__init__()
        self.p1 = self.addPlot(title="Plot 1")
        self.p1.setLabel("left", "Value", units="V")
        self.p1.setLabel("bottom", "Time", units="s")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        if item is self.p1.getAxis("left").label:
            print("clicked left")
        elif item is self.p1.getAxis("bottom").label:
            print("clicked bottom")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication([])
    win = QMainWindow()
    plot = AbstractPlot()
    win.setCentralWidget(plot)
    win.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(Qt.QtCore, "PYQT_VERSION"):
        QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, thanks for your answer, but that does not work for me, if I add print(item) after item=self.itemAt(event.pos()), wherever I click outside the plot rect (that is, left to the y-axis and below the x-axis), this gives the PlotItem but not AxisItem.

Comment: @ZongyueLu 1. Are you using my code without modifying it? 2. what version of pyqtgraph do you use?

Comment: yes.. I copy pasted your code, and my pyqtgraph version is 0.11.1, what is your version? I will try upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: The same version, I am on Linux.

Comment: I am also on Linux, my PyQt version is 5.15.2

Comment: I use PyQt5 5.15.5